# How to logout an user in opencms without session invalidate

Tags: content-management-system, opencms

I need to logout an user or switch to default(Guest) in OpenCms without invalidate the session.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `logout` method of http://files.opencms.org/javadoc/core/org/opencms/jsp/CmsJspLoginBean.html

Comment: In the source of this method there's a "session.invalidate()"